# Slope of the spherical cap

Tags: spherical-coordinates, spheres, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

I have a full spherical cap (lower part), with a known R and h. It is located on three needles at points A, B and C, which form an equilateral triangle and have the same coordinates Z. Point A and B are fixed, point C can move on the line formed by the AC points (x coordinate, y and z can be calculated because it moves on the sphere, how?). How the slope of the base plane will change by changing the position of point C.
Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: How is the "base plane" defined? Is the "line formed by the $AC$ points" literally the line between $A$ and $C$ at the same constant $z$ coordinate, or does the "line" refer only to the $x$ and $y$ coordinates plotted in the $x,y$ plane? Does the spherical cap move when $C$ does? Does $C$ stay in contact with the spherical cap? Does it matter that as soon as $C$ moves, the triangle will no longer be equilateral?

Comment: It's a equilateral triangle only at begging, Yes the spherical cap moves, when C does due to gravity. Point C always stay in contact with the spherical cap, it can moves  only on line AC to the end of a sphere. The base plane is the top of the spherical cap, the circle.

Comment: It's a good idea to edit the question to work that extra information into it, also to clearly state how things work (as well as you can). For one thing, saying that $C$ moves on the sphere seems misleading if what really happens is that the spherical cap moves to stay in contact with $C.$

Comment: It may still help to have more of what we call "context" for this question: if it's from a book, the author, title, and page number; if an exercise for a class, the specific subject within math you were studying; if a practical problem you encountered somewhere else, a description of what the needles and the cap really represent. If it was an exercise from a class or book you could also include the exact original wording (though your interpretation is valuable too).

Comment: There is certainly more information needed or additional assumptions to be made in order to solve this. Presumably these needles are “sticky:” with no friction, the cap will settle so that its “base plane” is level. So, then, what is the starting orientation and position of the cap relative to the three needles? All that’s given is that the cap is resting on them at start, but with “sticky” needles we’re not guaranteed that it starts off centered on them with its rim horizontal. You also haven’t given the initial distance between the needles, which I expect will affect the solution.

Comment: The preceding aside, this cap rotates about a fixed axis defined by the tips of the $A$ and $B$ needles. The problem reduces to computing the appropriate rotation angle to keep contact with the $C$ tip as that needle moves around.